# How can I iterate through command-line arguments with va_list in C

Tags: c, pointers, command-line, command-line-arguments

So I found myself wishing that I could iterate through command-line arguments with va_list and I believe I have seen it done somewhere.

I've tried googling with no avail.

Does anyone know how to achieve this or know if it can be achieved?

Comment: Is there a reason `argc` and `argv` are insufficient?

Comment: I have a feeling @hmjd's suggestion is a bit of an answer

Comment: Why should this be better than a simple `for` loop?

Answer (score 8):

You can't. `va_list` applies to varargs functions, which `main` is not. However, what I would like to know is why you would prefer this (if it were possible):

```
char *arg;
va_list vl;
va_start(vl, argc);
while ((arg = va_arg(vl, char*)))
    // use arg
va_end(vl);
```

to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
   // use argv[i]
```

or this:

```
for (char **arg = argv; *arg; ++arg)
   // use *arg
```

Comment: Can't you?  See my answer below.  It might contain errors, but it works reliably for me.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdarg/va_start/

This doesn't apply specifically to command lines arguments.

Answer (score -1):

Of course you can!

This is what I do (c99):

```
void get_model_parameters (char **argv, int argc, ...) {
    va_list _;
    va_start(_, argc);
    for (int i = 8; va_arg(_, long double *); i++) {
        *va_arg(_, long double *) = strtold(argv[i], NULL);
    }
    va_end(_);
}
```

I use it to get (long double in this case) command arguments from the tail of a command.  There are various "models" which I compile one at a time against a common framework, and each model possesses *its own* parameter set populated from the command arguments.  There are 8 (skipped) common command parameters first (including the program name!), then the model parameters start after that.

Comment: Looks like some mysteriously silent mod does not like me pointing out that this really DOES answer the question.  Never mind, maybe I just won't bother helping next time . . .